# Browser gets disconnected while executing karma test cases

Tags: javascript, angular, karma-jasmine, karma-runner

Hi I have somewhat around 603 testcases written in jasmine. And I am trying to run these test cases using **ng test** command. But every time browser gets disconnected at 390 testcase and restarts the browser again and runs the testcases again from number 1. Message is following:-

`HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 390 of 603 (14 FAILED) (0 secs / 37 mins 55.402 secs)
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
  Disconnected
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 390 of 603 (14 FAILED) DISCONNECTED (38 mins 45.052 secs / 37 mins 55.402 secs)
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Windows 7 0.0.0) ERROR
HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Windows 7 0.0.0): Executed 390 of 603 (14 FAILED) DISCONNECTED (38 mins 45.052 secs / 37 mins 55.402 secs)
26 08 2019 14:57:29.558:INFO [karma]: Restarting HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Windows 7 0.0.0) (1 of 5 attempts)
26 08 2019 14:57:33.062:INFO [HeadlessChrome 0.0.0 (Windows 7 0.0.0)]: Connected on socket CF0U7yNUkencldeeAAAB with id 69964403`

Karma.conf file

```
 module.exports = function(config) {
    config.set({
        basePath: '',
        frameworks: ['jasmine', '@angular-devkit/build-angular'],
        plugins: [
            require('karma-jasmine'),
            require('karma-phantomjs-launcher'),
            require('karma-chrome-launcher'),
            require('karma-junit-reporter'),
            require('karma-jasmine-html-reporter'),
            require('karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter'),
            require('@angular-devkit/build-angular/plugins/karma')
        ],
        client: {
            clearContext: false
        },
        coverageIstanbulReporter: {
            reports: ['html', 'lcovonly'],
            fixWebpackSourcePaths: true
        },
        angularCli: {
            environment: 'dev'
        },
        mime: {
            'text/x-typescript': ['ts']
        },
        reporters: ['progress', 'kjhtml', 'junit'],
        junitReporter: {
            outputFile: './target/surefire-reports/TEST-com.ericsson.bss.rm.cpm.cpc.xml',
            suite: 'com.ericsson.bss.rm.cpm.cpc',
            useBrowserName: false
        },
        port: 9876,
        failOnEmptyTestSuite: false,
        colors: true,
        logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
        autoWatch: false,
        mime: { 'text/x-typescript': ['ts', 'tsx'] },
        browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
        singleRun: true,
       captureTimeout: 800000,
       browserDisconnectTimeout: 2000,
       browserDisconnectTolerance: 5,
       browserNoActivityTimeout: 800000,
       webpack: { node: { fs: 'empty' } }
    });
};
```

Package.json file:-

```
"devDependencies": {
    "@angular/cli": "^8.2.0",
    "@ericsson/cus-ui": "3.0.0",
    "@types/jasmine": "2.8.8",
    "@types/jasminewd2": "~2.0.2",
    "@types/node": "~12.0.8",
    "codelyzer": "^5.0.1",
    "jasmine-core": "~2.8.0",
    "jasmine-spec-reporter": "~4.2.1",
    "karma": "~2.0.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "~2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "~1.0.1",
    "karma-coverage-istanbul-reporter": "^1.2.1",
    "karma-jasmine": "~1.1.0",
    "karma-jasmine-html-reporter": "^0.2.2",
    "karma-junit-reporter": "^1.2.0",
    "karma-phantomjs-launcher": "^1.0.4",
    "karma-remap-istanbul": "0.6.0",
    "karma-spec-reporter": "0.0.30",
    "protractor": "5.4.2",
    "ts-node": "~8.2.0",
    "tslint": "~5.17.0",
    "typescript": "~3.4.3"
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I experienced the exact same problem as you and managed to fix it by chance by defining a custom launcher for it:

```
browsers: ["Chrome-headless"],
            customLaunchers: {
                "Chrome-headless": {
                    base: 'Chrome',
                    flags: ['--headless', '--remote-debugging-port=9222', '--no-sandbox']
                }
            }
```

Or you can also try it out by adding this additional flag in  custom launcher:

```
--js-flags="--max_old_space_size=4096"
```

Comment: How to add the last js flag?

Comment: you can add the flag like => flags: ['--headless', '--remote-debugging-port=9222', '--no-sandbox ,  --max_old_space_size=4096 ']